# Ubuntu crashing/freezing while gaming

Tags: ubuntu, games

Using Ubuntu 18 recently (new hard drive). I have been having an issue with the system becoming unresponsive after less than ten minutes of gaming. I load up factorio, and start playing, then soon the entire system freezes. The mouse is still able to move normally, but no part of the system gui responds. I am running the game windowed, so I can click on other programs and try to open the terminal etc. However nothing happens. No keyboard shortcuts respond either. Not sure if this is a bug in the game or Ubuntu and would like suggestions on how to proceed with troubleshooting.

Edit: As far as I can tell from psensor this is not a thermal problem. Nothing is getting above 60 degrees C and this is a tower with decent fans, none of which are behaving abnormally. Clock also seem to run normally.

Comment: This could be a hardware heat problem. Try monitoring the temperature levels. Try loading the machine without running the same software. Look to see if the clock is still ticking (if so then output and, at least some, processing are working).

Comment: Please be specific with what info would be useful for OP to put into the question when down-voting, or voting to close. There is no way to improve unless you are specific.